# Overwhelmed by complex C#/ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have been hired as a junior programmer to work on projects that extend existing functionality in a very large, complex solution. The code base consists of C#, ASP.NET, jQuery, javascript, html and xml.

I have some knowledge of all these in addition to fair knowledge of object-oriented programming and its fundamental concepts of inheritance, abstraction, polymorphism and encapsulation. I can follow code up through its base classes, interfaces, abstract classes and understand a large part of the code that I read while doing this.

However, this solution is so humongous and so many things get tied together whenever I navigate through the code that I feel absolutely overwhelmed. I often find myself unable to fully follow everything that is going on with objects being serialized, large amounts of C# and javascript operating on the same pages and methods being called from template files that consist mainly of markup.

I love learning about code, but trying to deal with this really stresses me out.

Additionally, I do know that a significant amount of unit testing has been done but I know nothing about unit testing or how to utilize it.

Any advice anyone could offer me regarding dealing with a large code base while using Visual Studio 2008 would be greatly appreciated. Are there tools that I can use to help get a handle on what is going on? Perhaps there are things even in Visual Studio that I am not aware of. How can I follow the code to low level functionality in order to get a better grasp of what is going on at a high level?

Comment: Apologies; as much as I might sympathize with the situation you're in, the Q&A format of Stack Overflow doesn't support this kind of question well.  I'd recommend editing your question to try and focus on *specific* problems you're having which can be answered in a subjective, definitive way.

Comment: I feel for you man. Since you are a junior programmer, there should be a senior programmer that can give you a relatively simple bug fix for you to start off with.. Or maybe a relatively simple feature. I mean it is obvious that you won't understand 10s of thousands of lines of codes, hundreds of classes, and how they are all linked together in a month. Just have to start off simple

Comment: Also, as casper said, this question may be better suited at programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Give some time (one month at least) to understand what happens on this project. And I think that they must guide you on the architect of the project. With out papers and the struct of the data and work flow, is not easy to understand whats going on.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I am going to post this at programmers.stackexchange as suggested.